# Unusual session difficulty with curl - all easy solutions were tried already

Tags: php, xml, curl, cookies, session-cookies

Sup,

I am writing here as my last resort, noone in my country's php forum could handle this problem. If you could help me I would be really grateful.

I can't properly get session from one website using curl. So, basically I am trying to make 2 requests. Frist one is to create and save session, and the another is to make a request I want to make.

So the whole thing is the first reqest does not create a proper session. It saves some session to a file, but it doesn't work. Funny thing when I copy the session from my browser to the file, everything works ok.

So again, the first request saves a session to a file but the second request returns an error, but when I copy my browser's cookie value to cookie file (cookie3.txt) everything works properly. It is like the website knew the session in a file was made by curl.

I tried everything, extracting headers, cookie jar, everything, nothing seems to be working. Here is one of the sample codes to get the session (this with cookie jar).

```
$cookie_file = './cookie3.txt';

if (! file_exists($cookie_file) || ! is_writable($cookie_file)){
    echo 'Cookie file missing or not writable.';
    exit;
}



$chh = curl_init (html_entity_decode($strona));
curl_setopt ($chh, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($cookie_file));
curl_setopt ($chh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($chh, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($chh, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
//curl_setopt($chh, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($chh, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)');
$output = curl_exec ($chh);
curl_close($chh);


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath($cookie_file));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $strona);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$posty);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

// in real life you should use something like:
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
//          http_build_query(array('postvar1' => 'value1')));

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


$data = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($data);
```

This is th error I get after using the cookie this code created:

```
<partial-response><changes><update id="wyszukiwarka_pub_form:messages"><![CDATA[<div id="wyszukiwarka_pub_form:messages" class="ui-messages ui-widget" aria-live="polite" data-global="false" data-summary="data-summary" data-detail="data-detail" data-severity="all,error" data-redisplay="true"></div>]]></update><update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[H4sIAAAAAAAAAM1ZbWwcxRken2Nih4QGJ4FQ4uA4gRBw1r74kthx08SJneTAdgJnzEeEjrnd8d34
9nY3s7O3exfiNqA2fAipElQVCEQkkAAp9A/9Uf4UIUAIEBFEQkggJARUFUIgVKFWbSXad3bv09m9Dwcn3R9zs3fvzLzzPs/7MXNnvkVthsnQlbM4iyWLU1U6hM3UBDbaln7y+htX3fdhKwodQMtUHSsHsMx1FkUdPMWImdJVxTH27EX
i6bfboRX99RztsnNm3kpTG7M0jhtWIj6js8wuk6hE5vtTRE4ndGeCaNaIJebTOGEGIxzLs9RiaNXRcVc
X
FWtJ6XBiFsYM/+7sXc+uNLeoIYQcAxYJWcfQHGqt6rUZ8JTels4xdJOYx5FmsExMSdYzhq4RjUt3RKOaYfFNR5huEMZzt
5KciQpPJyzA0BVlBcY0K1P5o8FRWxarVCnZzBXbp+sqwdr73ezXHz397+9CqOUeV84ijtECqtwcpMphi
9
fSRWyngxemyjK0JKtTBZUfx5gTIu0crVB1GavTQi5GuCm+XY7AIhytt3MaTVMPBAVzPIUTKtk1G6cKDw/uKBuw1Gspmxe2uRX0lUxLK2gvWhVWkIgqTeHkBOEpXRlzAEHTpLpWUKxluWvJa7x9g+h8Odz5w6Z9Xx7
jIVduVUmuLPHcbx6J/f2ec79wQQc9enSWlLCB5RTxmzCaMdTov/Cnavj+DcsLprvW3oakjccr+XjESqhUzmt4H+AlZeCrUV22MoDGjYoubzmB0HwOxjijWnL45XPTf/u66/jBIgdbOOqqRJVkBaIjMgddxkTfMBz7OMr1ZSmxzb4KHWjlC95qFDWSnBTPqN17Izu29YbDO7uxO9c4NT
nRCNvd09xGehyXBOvtvU2boIL/08A3lw3dAlXYklHklJ+Le5zatt3HPQMdVXSWiWaFaH4mmk7RrBLNmgYYPFSHwaL384ItFkKH4u5bRKdH
oJpHzgJQ3RnpjQz8P4O60R9UYfA7cwrWKB7Vm0B2BYe0gRNEVYmSyIG31OBMJAJBUgoKkvuL/Xpxsj1BNQWc1TQLIcXLaCOM4ZwwuXPyXNeTb+NnWlFLFC0xaZ64rtxqLxEtDLrBX4UYx5wcgoRHWAxnC
bv73Vd2P/70+xMhFBpHHbKKTXMSZwhHnW7c6BNW7ivEjXG0zIQxijsHR1d5ElTvixFGIZPkBZeHAYKs2ARy8d0j0o
xru8IrqNZbMwy7gT8oCq8tRdd5Yo/86vPRF9o33R0qmHAdrLOhOszOGyGibPtjPT+eeujlPxej7CF7GG3eeDxjJo9urnQIKc1yXGzSwBrMpOi
b7z2BVs5P7sKh0og271AQInsh1nS7uVE4UkMK9DgOUG17c1Q7wmgW0PNh3GrMAeaExYk5lcJ8hJWy727
h
Gi6xQgUQXYB3F15EO+Y0FvyCQ21k6CcOtdf6rwZVEGFNLHW56AyX7FB0sPLW91eaoUhy8XHQbW+xD6KB
+
oi6ao3qaTfOWYH0spHVPL0GBiO94e2Rxul1njJANbGXiQA6iPa2ZtlwXUBtnUtqmFsMX1SM9okkVM8sJ
d
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
3/teulb54y//SPIjlRGYptl4AUb1bbtU1oEq4bNoTptgZ5uchxt+t63UNf0dPF62n4aUMFK/svvX9c708xAyhmUDO3OLE24ChfWrQWnUXnHff1vQKvuv1nw0xOwXeqRprQ3tV5sM6xZkdESF1QbTqJdt
UvCi07n1SJolE8O1LaTGCdOofuX8AxYqgfTqlDjReqQTotRtG6rjqEjuY0nKGyd4dplhZC7kLI4ejmgN
O
Hqts4nlYtOa/bi1Q9bGlo6eZ4XetGatCvXrvA8sfnErOZRRrIM6Mwb91LMqbbUUiG3lXi6f/CU6vYamTKJTClWQrAq8V/Ei3rIAvMUGZy8XJdgxeMh5UFhJKaF4vhC44kMbSngbsl2EPc9jYRp5V/aQWGkwfRyQVcevVDONnZzKVXLcUWI6YE3CDNMJy/uLcTv0Q31TePq1YgRBmUbh6iwXBvONIEQkUVFgOMSKN/xU7ljNLV1U8a+Jz/AU77FZdiHgAA]]></update></changes></partial-response>
```

Here is a sample cookie3.txt file after algorithm is used:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

#HttpOnly_site.com    FALSE    /    FALSE    0    JSESSIONID    3b-cKghsA2BoutqFYZzc0Min
```

Comment: Why are you not setting `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` in your second request ?

Comment: I have tried that before it did not make a difference, when I changed a session number it still worked. But yes I have tried that.

Comment: maybe we could help more if we could actually test it ourselves, what's the url? and you may be missing out a javascript/XMLHttpRequest-based script detection test